# Height of dataview list in sencha touch based on number of items

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

I need to adjust the height of dataview list in sencha touch based on number of items. What I have done so far is just this configs in that list

```
    config: {
        fullscreen: true,
         height:'100%'
   store: 'CategoryListStoresecond',
        loadingText: "Loading ...",
        emptyText: "<div>No items found.</div>",
        onItemDisclosure: true,
        grouped: false,
        itemTpl : '<div id="{Name}"> <img src="{Image}" /> <!--<h2>{Name}</h2>--!><p>{Name}</p></div>',
},
```

Comment: not sure about touch but extjs has wrap property that you can configure for this.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do it like

```
var store = list.getStore();

store.load( { callback: function(records, operation, success) {
    list.setHeight({items.height} * records.length);
});
```

I did and it works. but i think you have to make sure there is not too many records. and the list is not scrollable.

no need set the full screen and height in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using maxHeight & minHeight if you want http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.Component-cfg-maxHeight

Also if it is covering inside `vbox` layout you can use `flex` to control the height.

Comment: How can I know the height to be set? It is based on number of items on the list